# Sharepoint inserts usning shareplum library

Tags: python, python-3.x, shareplum

I have a sharepoint list in which I am trying to add a new item.The list has an owner column of the type "Users" . My code fails to insert a new row with empty value for this column.
It fails with an "Attribute Error" stating " Cannot insert ' ' into owner".
Any pointers?